# How to replace Bitmap.ClearRect from FMX replace on VCL?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, vcl, bitmapimage

I try to rewrite an FMX project in VCL.

Code for QR-code drawing in FMX:

```pascal
for Column := 0 to QRCode.Columns - 1 do
begin
  if QRCode.IsBlack[Row, Column] then
    QRCodeBitmap.ClearRect(TRectF.Create(PointF(Column, Row) * Scale,
      Scale, Scale), TAlphaColors.Black);
end;
```

How to replace `QRCodeBitmap.ClearRect()` in VCL?

I try like this:

```
if (QRCode.IsBlack[Row, Column]) then
begin
  QRCodeBitmap.Canvas.Pixels[Column, Row] := clBlack;
end else
begin
  QRCodeBitmap.Canvas.Pixels[Column, Row] := clWhite;
end;
```

but it does not work like I want.

Answer (score 1):

The [`TBitmap.ClearRect()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Graphics.TBitmap.ClearRect) method in FMX fills a rectangular area with a color.

In VCL, you can do the same thing using the [`TBitmap.Canvas.FillRect()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Graphics.TCustomCanvas.FillRect) method, where the fill color is specified in the [`TBitmap.Canvas.Brush.Color`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Graphics.TBrush.Color) property, eg:

```
for Column := 0 to QRCode.Columns - 1 do
begin
  if QRCode.IsBlack[Row, Column] then
  begin
    QRCodeBitmap.Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlack;
    QRCodeBitmap.Canvas.FillRect(TRect.Create(Point(Column * Scale, Row * Scale),
      Scale, Scale));
  end;
end;
```